# When to create a baseline and does it ever change?

Tags: windows, performance-monitoring

I have got this question as mentioned in title about creating baselines after reading an article on using performance monitor in Windows OS.

I understand that I need a baseline to compare performance but the question I am wondering over and over is: When to create this baseline? The article mentioned that you should create it under normal workloads. Okay, what qualifies as normal here?

Does a baseline ever change? So, say I captured my baseline today. Is it going to stay the same forever? When does it change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand and use baseline performance indicators, they aren't static.
Don't consider your baseline something you take once then forget about!

What you want to do is create scheduled tasks that take performance metrics during a long enough period that it encompasses your peak and lowest usage.
In the vast majority of situations this means a full week of metrics.
Keep in mind though, this depends on you being able to take these statistics without major impact (which in almost all cases is quite easy)

Then you decide for a retention period, and a refresh period.
For example, you retain the statistics for a year, and take new ones monthly.
In this example, you would take a week of statistics each month, and keep a years worth.

What this gives you is:

1. A pretty good idea of your average performance
2. A history of performance long enough to be able to map trends
3. A small enough repository of metrics that you don't end up with too much data

As for when to start...
After you need it is too late, so start today.
If your customer cares if it performs badly, get a baseline.

Comment: I don't really understand. Why take a baseline if you can simply tell from performance logs if your server is underload or overload?

Comment: @user12313 Because a baseline allows you to show trends in your performance logs. For example, you look at a server and think *oh it's underload!* because it has 90% of resources available. But every friday it runs a massive ETL job that takes all those resources so you shouldn't be touching it... Or you look at a server and think "oh it's overloaded!" But in truth it was fine until a week ago when the app on it was updated and the update had a memory leak. In truth you need to notify the app owner that something changed, not add more resources and increase cost.

Comment: @user12313 So what I'm trying to say is, you can't properly assess performance by looking at a snapshot (you can make some educated guesses sure, but certainty requires more data)

Comment: Okay. Can there be more than one baselines or how can I know when to replace the baseline? Usually what I have heard is, you take a baseline when your system is brand new. This really got me confusing. A brand new system with no server load or what?

Comment: @user12313 The purpose of the baseline is to have something to compare to when the customer tells you his app has gotten slow. Or just to go and review performance to see if you need to add resources. You refresh it as often as you think is necessary, but personally I would consider statistics older than a month to be too old to diagnose a problem today. (but very useful to check for long term trends)

Comment: What can I consider a normal baseline in the first place without misinterpreting it with an under- or overload?

Comment: @user12313 At first you can't it and it really depends on the app. For a sharepoint site I consider one working day of statistics to already be useable. For anything that has reporting or data analysis I want at least a full week of data and preferably even a month. There's other obvious stuff, such as don't judge a business app during a weekend...

Comment: Reaces: Okay, I guess I finally understood the point. 1.) You capture the data for week or month to form a good baseline and then 2.) You compare it every day to get a judgement of how well is the performance going on. Right?